# Merge cells in a column by pairs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to merge two rows in Excel. Here is a screenshot of the worksheet: 
[image]

As you can see, every cell of the "A" column is composed by two rows. I need to merge the two rows into one, with the text from both of the rows. If I try to join cells, it retains only text from the upper row.

[Here](http://www.gruppofas.eu/1.xlsx) I've uploaded a sample of the .xls file.

Comment: Here is another way to do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75468486/5091720

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CONCATENATE formula to merge cell contents without using any VBA.

Example: if you want to merge the contents of cells A1 and A2, you could use the following formula in cell A3:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1," ",A2)
```

The quotation marks are there to make a space between the contents of cells A1 and A2.

You can then select cell A3, copy it, and select 'paste values' to convert the formula to the raw data it contains.

Comment: Note: You can accomplish the same thing by using the ampersand: `=A1&" "&A2`.