# Need a macro for Concate two columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I wants to merge Col "Name" with Col "Lastname" based on their header name & create a new column "Name" paste their that merged values & delete old "Name" column

[image]

Need like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this. I would think you would want a space between names so I will use " " here to show the space. If you don't want that just use "".
Formula ways

1. =TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,B2:C2)
2. =B2 &" "& C2

---

no space option

3. =CONCAT(B3:C3)

---

There is also the powerquery way. This is a good way if you have to open the same file to do the same thing time after and time again. It will also not show formulas. Select the top left cell of data and hit the keys `Ctrl + t`  this turns your data into a defined table. Next click on `Data > From Table/Range`
The Power Query editor will open and you choose `Tranform > Merge Columns` choose the separator and the new Column name `OK`. Then click `File > Close & Load`.

There are other reasons to use power query such as you want to scrape data out of a csv files or website without opening it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365 and want only one Formula to create the new table, you can use this formula:

```
=LET(Header,A1:C1, data,A2:C4,
dataMerged,HSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(data,1) & CHOOSECOLS(data,2),DROP(data,,-1)),
VSTACK(Header,dataMerged))
```